# Google Drive Desktop on CentOS

Tags: centos, google-drive

Hope you guys are fine. I want a Google Drive folder on my CentOS 6.8 desktop like what we have on windows. I will link that folder to my school account and it will start syncing my local files on the web everyday. Problem is I do not know if there is nay way I can do this. That is install Google Drive Desktop on CentOS same like what we have on Windows PC.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Google hasn't released Google Drive for the linux desktop. (see https://tools.google.com/dlpage/drive).  There are some open source efforts to duplicate the ability, but none of them have been built for CentOS or EPEL.  You will have to use the web interface to upload/download files from your Google Drive.

Answer (score 0):

I am using insync (https://www.insynchq.com/) for a couple of years now and it works like a charm. I switched to insync+gdrive because I had problems with the linux dropbox client not syncing some files.

It has an one time fee, which has changed over the years a couple of times. At some point it was free for @gmail.com accounts but not for gsuite accounts. I am not sure of the current pricing.